# Executable Ruby Scripts Using the Current Local User RVM Install?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I would like ruby scripts with the header `#! /usr/bin/ruby` to execute using the currently in use rvm version of ruby.  I run into the issue where I am using a given version but upon executing the script the system ruby is invoked.  Installing RVM for every user on the system is not an option.

Problem:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

/usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

How to make it the following without performing a system wide install of RVM?

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you do `which ruby`, you'll find that RVM's `ruby` does not lie at `/usr/bin/ruby`. Instead use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This will tell it to look up which `ruby` to use in the current environment (essentially the `$PATH`).

You could also execute your script via `ruby` itself: `ruby myscript.rb`